# Cherry Pick a Squashed Commit

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-squash

I have two main branches, `staging` and `master`. I have a few commits and I have pushed those changes to a branch say `xyz` whose base branch is staging and have created a pull request for `staging` branch. All these commits has been squashed into a single commit.

Is it possible to cherry pick this squashed commit and apply this cherry pick to a new branch started from `master`, so that I can create the same pull request to `master` branch also.

Comment: Yes, sounds perfectly reasonable. What makes you believe it's not?

Comment: as long as you have the hash of the commit, you can cherry-pick it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to cherry pick this squashed commit and apply this cherry pick to a new branch started from master

Yes: `git cherry-pick <sha of squashed commit>`

Comment: I see that squashed commits also have parents so this solution doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @user1870400 - you can cherry pick multiple commits, but you'll need to run `cherry-pick` for each commit you want moved, one at a time, and in the order you want them applied (generally oldest first)